# How to input Promise string value into an object

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

In the code below

```
const getOptionName = async(id): Promise<void> => {
  const data = await dealStore.findById(id)
  console.log('data.optionName', data.optionName)
  console.log('typeof(data.optionName)', typeof(data.optionName))

  return data.optionName
}

const openRemoveDialog = (): void => {
  const checkedItems = grid1.current.getCustomCheckedList().map(item => {
    return {
      optionName: getOptionName(item.id),
      channelName: item?.channelName,
      name: item?.name,
      id: item.id,
    }
  })
  console.log('checkedItems', checkedItems)
}
```

My `console.log('data.optionName', data.optionName)` outputs

```
data.optionName 딜 옵션명 테스트
```

My `console.log('typeof(data.optionName)', typeof (data.optionName))` outputs

```
typeof(data.optionName) string
```

My `console.log('checkedItems', checkedItems)` gives the following output

[image]

I am confused why my `optionName` value is a `Promise` instead of a string when `console.log('typeof(data.optionName)', typeof (data.optionName))` shows me that `data.optionName` is a `string`

I want my `optionName` value to be a `string` and not a `Promise`. How do I input the `PromiseResult` `string` value into my `optionName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getOptionName` is an `async` function, so it will return a promise. To get the value out of that promise you'll need to `await` it. In order to `await` it your map function needs to be an `async` function, which means you're creating an array of promises. You can then use `Promise.all` to combine the array of promises, and `await` it to get your finished array of objects.

```
const openRemoveDialog = async (): void => {
  const promises = grid1.current.getCustomCheckedList().map(async (item) => {
    return {
      optionName: await getOptionName(item.id),
      channelName: item?.channelName,
      name: item?.name,
      id: item.id,
    }
  })
  const checkedItems = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log('checkedItems', checkedItems)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If possible you should change your Promise to ask for `findByIds(ids: number[])` to get all data matching a set of IDs rather than one singular ID - this will reduce the number of network calls and remove the anti-pattern of making Promises within your `map` closure.

But if you want to not retrieve a Promise for `optionName` you'll also have to `await` the result of that promise as well.

```js
return await data.optionName;
```